# Send float list in flask output

Tags: python, numpy

I have to send lists of text embeddings in flask output. The output looks as follows:

```
{"embeddings":[[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.4,0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8,0.9]]}
```

I tried doing json.dumps and jsonify from flask but still I get following error when sending above output in flask response:

```
TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should provide the code you want to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that into a native Python data type before serializing it to JSON

```
import numpy as np

embeddings = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]], dtype=np.float32)
```